# Why does this code result in an empty file?

Tags: c++

After I run this code the file "balances.txt" contains no data.  Maybe I am misunderstanding how fstream works or I'm confused about the flow direction?

```
//
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream bank_file;

    bank_file.open("balances.txt", fstream::app);
    int count = 0;
    float number = 0.0;
    for (bank_file >> number; count < 100; bank_file >> number)
{
    bank_file << number << endl;
    number++;
    count++;
    cout << number << endl;
    
}
   bank_file.close();
```

Comment: What do you think `fstream::app` means?

Comment: You can't read from a file open for append.  All of your `bank_file >> number` are probably failing, which your code doesn't check for.  What is this code actually supposed to do?

Comment: I wanted the code to just open a file "balances.txt" and then the loop would write the numbers 1 to 100 into the file.  That's why I used fstream::app.   I wanted it to append each value in the loop into the file.

Answer (score 0):

To write the numbers 1 to 100 in the file, replace the `for` loop in your example with the following:

```
for( int number = 1; number <= 100; ++number)
{
    bank_file << number << "\n";
}
```

Note that there are good reasons not to use floating point numbers to represent bank balances. Chief among these is rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream bank_file;

    bank_file.open("balances.txt", fstream::app);
    int count = 0;
    float number = 0.0;
    for (count= 0; count <= 100; count++)
        {
            bank_file << number << endl;
            cout << number << endl;
            number++;
            
        }
   bank_file.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.   Think I overcomplicated the issue with the attempt to use fstream operators in the do statement.